# C# List<T> Slower When Re-Assigned

Tags: c#, list, sqlite, visual-studio-2008

I am using VS 2008, C#, Sqlite and ObjectListView. I have a method to query database (using datareader) then return List and assign to other List. Why when I call that method and re-assign to List, it need more and more time to re-assign even I clear or set it null. I test it using stopwatch. First assign it need about 300 milliseconds, second assign about 800 milliseconds, third assign more than 1000 millisecond, and keep going up. Btw, sorry about my english.

```
public static List<Document> GetCompanyDocument(int companyId)
{
    List<Document> docs = new List<Document>();

    using (IDSDataAccess.IDSDataSqlite db = new IDSDataAccess.IDSDataSqlite())
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("SELECT document.*, prep.userInitial AS userPrep, Rev.userInitial AS userInitial ")
            .Append("FROM document ")
            // more sql command 
            .Append("WHERE document.compId = @compId ")
            .Append("ORDER BY parent ASC, name ASC;");


        db.CommandText = sb.ToString();
        db.AddParameter("@compId", DbType.Int32, companyId);
        db.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        db.Open();

        db.ExecuteReader();                

        using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader reader = db.DbDataReader as SQLiteDataReader)
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Document doc = new Document();
                    // do more action
                    docs.Add(doc);
                }
            }

            if (reader != null)
            {
                if (!reader.IsClosed)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
        sb = null;

        db.Close();
    }

    return docs;
}



// Other method
List<Document> docs = GetCompanyDocument(1);
```

Comment: Is it the assignment that's taking longer or retrieving the query results? I'm guessing it's the actual query that's taking longer for some reason.

Comment: What's the code you use to test how long it's taking? Does the test include how long it takes to retrieve the query response from the database?

Comment: The `sb.Remove(...)`, `sb = null;` and `db.Close()` parts can all be removed - along with the reader explicit closing. Trust the garbage collector and `using` statements.

Comment: I am using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch and use ElapsedMilliseconds. I try to test query time, and query need is about 300 miliseconds for some testing. I think query stable.

Comment: There might be a problem in your timing code then. Assignment of a list to a variable is about as quick as you can imagine. It doesn't copy the list or anything (it's a reference type), it just says "docs point to this list in memory now".

Comment: It would be helpful to see your stopwatch code. Are you creating a new stopwatch each time or are you using start/restart?

Comment: I am using start/stop/reset

Comment: Where are you actually calling the GetCompanyDocument(1) method? Due to how the time is multiplying it sounds like this method might be called multiple times. When you set a break point in this method, does it only get hit once per action? Could the event that initiates the GetCompanyDocument method be getting registered more than once?

Comment: Shouldn't your `if (reader != null)` be outside your `if (reader.HasRows)`?